# Creating GetCapabilities document in more languages

Tags: metadata, services, internationalization, inspire

I'm providing INSPIRE metadata and services and I want them in more languages than one. I expect that most users are locals, but some users are definitely from other European countries. Therefore I want to support national language and English. In metadata documents, I have used `gmd:PT_FreeText_PropertyType`, but GetCapabilities file follows other XSD schemas (WMS or WFS, according to the service).

Do you know about some possibilities of adding additional language to GetCapabilities document?

Comment: @lele3p what would you suggest then? in ISO 19115 implementation guide is sugessted to use PT_Freetext element for embedding a translation(using the subelement textGroup). Also for alternate languages the locale property of MD_Metadata is recommended.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150286)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150286)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using MapServer to provide multi-lingual variants of all titles and abstracts in a GetCapabilities response.

http://www.mapserver.org/ogc/inspire.html#multi-language-support-for-certain-capabilities-fields

Answer (score 0):

Is the server that should provide different capabilities document according to a language parameter. You cannot solve the multilanguage problem using the PT_Freetext parameter, especially because clients do not expect to read that tag to find relevant information.
The same problem stands for metadata: multilanguage metadata means that textual fields should be duplicated for each language and that the CSW server must respond with the requested language record.